Typeorm parent object not updating relation
I'm new to typeorm and typescript in general, coming from python sqlalchemy and django models.
What I'm trying to create is in essence a doubly linked list in typeorm.
I'm looking for a way to update the child relation of a parent field when creating a child related to the parent.
Entity:
@Entity()
export class StoryNode {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column('text')
    text: string;

    @Column({ type: "int", nullable: true })
    prevNodeId: number;

    @OneToOne(
        () => StoryNode, (storynode) => storynode.nextNode,
        { nullable: true }
    )
    @JoinColumn({ name: "prevNodeId" })
    prevNode: StoryNode;

    @Column({ type: "int", nullable: true })
    nextNodeId: number;

    @OneToOne(
        () => StoryNode, (storynode) => storynode.prevNode,
        { nullable: true, cascade: true }
    )
    @JoinColumn()
    nextNode: StoryNode;
}

The entities are created from the following jsons.
Parent:
{
  "name": "Node 1",
  "text": "string"
}

Child:
{
  "name": "Node 2",
  "text": "string",
  "prevNodeId": 1
}

Getting entities after creation:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Node 1",
    "text": "string",
    "prevNodeId": null,
    "nextNodeId": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Node 2",
    "text": "string",
    "prevNodeId": 1,
    "nextNodeId": null
  }
]

I tried googling related issues but couldn't find any. When adding the relation to my find option i can se that the relation works on the child, but is still not updated on the parent.
I would expect that after creating Node 2 with prevNodeId set to Node 1 id, that the nextNodeId would be updated to the id of Node 2.
Am i correct in expecting this behavior and how do i fix it, or should i handle it somehow differently?
